# FetchMore not updating data with queryroot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo

I'm trying to get some products in a specific collection and show them on the screen. However, I don't want to load all the products at the same time so, I'm getting 20 at a time. Earlier, I was using a query to read-only products based on some filters, and fetchmore() was working fine but now I'm using queryroot to fetch products in a collection, fetchmore() has stopped working. It sends network requests and load the data but doesn't render the page to include the results in the UI as well.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "../styles/ProductGrid.css";
// import PriceFilter from './PriceFilter';
import TypeFilter from "./TypeFilter/TypeFilter";
import { useQuery, gql, NetworkStatus } from "@apollo/client";


function ProductGrid() {

  const [queryVariables, setQueryVariables] = useState({ first: 20, handle: "exclusive-deals" });
  
  const { loading, error, data, fetchMore, refetch, networkStatus } = useQuery(
    QUERY,
    {
      variables: queryVariables,
      // notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
      fetchPolicy: "network-and-cache",
    }
  );

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error){
  return <p>{console.log(error)}</p>;
  }
  if (networkStatus === NetworkStatus.refetch)
    return <p>{console.log("Refetching!")}</p>;

  let productEdges = data.collectionByHandle.products.edges;

  console.log(productEdges);

  return (
    <div className="outContainer">
      {/* <PriceFilter/> */}
      <TypeFilter getFilters={setqueryVariables} />
      {/* test button */}
      <div className="product-grid">
        {productEdges.map((element, index) => {
          // formatting the price
          let tempPrice = Math.floor(
            element.node.priceRange.minVariantPrice.amount
          );
          let productPrice = new Intl.NumberFormat().format(tempPrice);

          return (
            <div className="container" key={index}>
              <div className="image-container">
                <img
                  src={element.node.images.edges[0].node.transformedSrc}
                  alt={element.node.title}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="product-title">{element.node.title}</div>
              <div className="product-title">{element.node.productType}</div>
              <div>
                {element.node.priceRange.minVariantPrice.currencyCode}.{" "}
                {productPrice}
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
      {/* load more products button */}
      <button
        className="load-more"
        onClick={() => {
          const endCursor =
            data.collectionByHandle.products.edges[data.collectionByHandle.products.edges.length - 1].cursor;

          fetchMore({
            variables: {
              after: endCursor,
              queryVariables
            }
          });
          console.log(loading)
          // setQueryVariables({first: 20, handle: "exclusive-deals", after:endCursor} )
        }}
      >
        Load More
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

// graphql query for products fetching
const QUERY = gql`
RootQuery Fetch($handle: String!, $after: String, $first:Int) 
{
      collectionByHandle(handle: $handle) {
        id
        description
        products(first: $first, after:$after) {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              description
              priceRange {
                minVariantPrice {
                  amount
                  currencyCode
                }
              }
              updatedAt
              productType
              title
              images(first: 1) {
                edges {
                  node {
                    transformedSrc(maxWidth: 300)
                  }
                }
              }
            }
            cursor
          }
          pageInfo {
            hasNextPage
          }
        }
      }
    }
`;

export default ProductGrid;
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './styles/index.css';
import App from './components/App';
import {ApolloClient,InMemoryCache, ApolloProvider, HttpLink, concat, ApolloLink} from '@apollo/client';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { relayStylePagination } from "@apollo/client/utilities"; 

// endpoint for storefront API
const httpLink = new HttpLink({uri: 'https://xxx.myshopify.com/api/graphql'});


// adding helper function that's responsible for merging and read capabilities in pagination
/*
  @Apollo docs:
  Relay-style pagination can be implemented in Apollo Client using merge and read functions,
  which means all the thorny details of connections and edges and pageInfo can be abstracted away,
  into a single, reusable helper function
*/

const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    RootQuery: {
      fields: {
        products: relayStylePagination(),
      },
    },
  },
});

// adding headers so we can authenticate using access token for storefront API
const authMiddleware = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  // add the authorization to the headers
  operation.setContext({
    headers: {
      'X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token': '1234567890'
    }
  });

  return forward(operation);
})

// initializing apolo client to send requests
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: concat(authMiddleware, httpLink),
  cache: cache
});


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <App />
    </ApolloProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
  

);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
reportWebVitals();
```

Also, I have tried changing the fetchPolicy to cache-only, network-only, network-and-cache and it doesnt work. howevere it works with this query

```
const QUERY = gql`
  query productFetch($first: Int, $after: String, $query: String) {
    products(first: $first, after: $after, query: $query) {
      edges {
        node {
          priceRange {
            minVariantPrice {
              amount
              currencyCode
            }
          }
          updatedAt
          productType
          title
          images(first: 1) {
            edges {
              node {
                transformedSrc(maxWidth: 300)
              }
            }
          }
        }
        cursor
      }
      pageInfo {
        hasNextPage
      }
    }
  }
`;
```